# Use R to cluster by SOM

Tags: machine-learning

How can I use SOM(self organizing map) method in R to cluster without identifying the number of clusters? I use the package of "Kohonen"in R, but it force you to set the number of clusters by somgrid().

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing the point of SOM model. It is **not** clustering method. It is supposed to place a low-dimensional grid of neurons inside your data, you can later on use this low-dimensional (finite!) representation to perform clustering, but SOM as it is is not giving you clustering. In particular somgrid does not accept "number of clusters" but rather the topology of the grid you want to fit into data. If you do not want to specify this topology go for **growing neural gas** which is pretty much SOM with "automatically" growing topology. There are also R packages implementing it, such as [gmum.R](http://r.gmum.net/).